# how to set opacity of the background image leaving foreground image?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

i am implementing a crousel with twitter bootstrap, and on my slider i have a foreground image as current image and background image as the next image, now i want to set the opacity of just the background image, how to set its opacity? please find my code below

CSS code

```
.carousel
{
background-image:url("img_tree.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
} 

.carousel .item {
  align: 'center';
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

HAML code

```
  #carousel-example-generic.carousel.slide
    %ol.carousel-indicators
      %li.active{"data-slide-to" => "0", "data-target" => "#carousel-example-generic"}
      %li{"data-slide-to" => "1", "data-target" => "#carousel-example-generic"}
      %li{"data-slide-to" => "2", "data-target" => "#carousel-example-generic"}
    / Wrapper for slides
    .carousel-inner
      - images_for_carousel.each do |item|
        - if item == 1
          .item.active
            = image_tag("slide#{item}.jpg", :alt => "image_#{item}")
            .carousel-caption
        - else
          .item
            = image_tag("slide#{item}.jpg", :alt => "image_#{item}")
    / Controls
    = link_to("#carousel-example-generic", class: "left carousel-control", "data-slide" => "prev") do
      %span.icon-prev
    = link_to("#carousel-example-generic", class: "right carousel-control", "data-slide" => "next") do
      %span.icon-next
```

jquery code

```
  $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel().on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    var previous_image_number = parseInt($('.carousel').css('background-image').match(/([0-9].jpg)/)) + 1;
    $('.carousel').css('background-image', 'url(' + '/assets/slide' + previous_image_number + '.jpg' + ')')
  })
```

image

[image: this is how carousel looks]

Comment: can you give jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understood you correctly, can you try this:

**edit: made a class of it**

Create a css class:

```
.imageBG {
        background: url(image.png);
        background-color: #fff; /* IE 8 */
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        *background-color: #fff; /* IE 7 */
    }
```

Add this class with Jquery:

```
$( "yourelement" ).addClass( "imageBG" );
```

See http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/ for more information about rgb alpha tranperancy

With pure jQuery you can add this like:

```
$("element").css({
"background": "url(image.png)",
"background-color": "#fff",
"background-color": "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
"*background-color": "#fff"
});
```

**Edit**

If you want to do this on the .carousel element you can do this  (no need for jQuery, just CSS):

```
.carousel
{
background:url("img_tree.png");
background-color: #fff; /* IE 8 */
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
*background-color: #fff; /* IE 7 */
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: @Sachin Singh: You should try to append this custom class `#image` to the second image via `jquery or javascript`

Comment: Can you make a jFiddle, or put it online somewhere, so we could preform some tests ? Which element you mean specific, Do you mean .carousel?

Comment: @Mike tried with no success, i think `rbga` will not make background image transparent but it can create a back of color transparent.

Comment: The problem here is that css cant change, the transparancy of an css background image. You better could place it in the DOM and then position it behind your slider useing z-index. Then you could apply opacity. Another solution would be (if the image inst dynamicly changed) to just edit the opacity in an editor program and save it as en PNG.

Answer (score 0):

kindly try this one hope it'll help

```
.bg{
opacity: 0.9;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```